# How to add the PCI ID to a serial port driver?

Tags: linux, configuration, real-time, drivers

```
linux-y3pi:~ # lspci | grep -i ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 01)

linux-y3pi:~ # lspci -n | grep 01:00.0
01:00.0 0200: 10ec:8136 (rev 01)
```

From here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-supported-pci-hardware-drivers.html

> Sample Output:
>   00:1b.0 0403: 8086:27d8 (rev 01) Where,
>
> - 00:1b.0 - Device
> - 8086 - constructor code for Intel Corporation
> - 27d8 - The model id.

So, I opened:
[/usr/src/f/rtnet/drivers/experimental/rt_r8169.c](http://read.pudn.com/downloads108/sourcecode/unix_linux/network/446580/rtnet-0.9.10/drivers/experimental/rt_r8169.c__.htm)

The relevant code (IMO):

```
static struct pci_device_id rtl8169_pci_tbl[] __devinitdata = {
        { 0x10ec, 0x8169, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0x1186, 0x4300, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, 0 },    /* <kk> D-Link DGE-528T */
        {0,},
};
```

**So, for me this info will be:

`{ 0x10ec, 0x8136, PCI_ANY_ID, PCI_ANY_ID, 0, 0, 0 },`

?**

**Is this the place where I have to add this PCI information and simply do a make and make install then?**

Comment: why is the close vote? what's offtopic in this?

Comment: Why not just use a current kernel instead of trying to keep that antique 2.4 kernel going? The current r8169 driver has had support for 10ec:8136 for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the correct driver for that device, then that is the correct location for that line. You may want to see if the existing module has some way to force IDs so you can verify this.